# Slow linking in release with optimization disabled

Tags: visual-c++, linker

I have a project (VC2005) which takes an unreasonable time (over 40 min) to link in Release while it is linked in less than 5 sec in Debug.

Both builds have incremental linking disabled and all files are located on the same drive.
Disabling Linker optimization in Release does not help.

Task manager never shows more than 150,000 K memory used by linker, which for a computer with 3GB of RAM is nothing.

I am building much bigger projects and never noticed such difference in building time.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: In addition I have dual core cpu and task manager shows 50% cpu used all the time, so all time is spend in the linker.

Comment: I don't know msvc, but GNU LD takes magnitudes of extra mem and time for dead code elimination. If the binary from both builds (release and debug) have vastly different sizes, try to see if you can find some option to disable trying to eliminate unused code.

Comment: Maybe /LTCG (link time code generation) enabled? But I doubt that this makes the different between 5sec vs. 40min. There must be an essential difference between the two configurations in the project.

Answer (score -1):

As remarked, the most probable reason is /LTCG (whole program optimization).

Other factors might be individual files compiled with /Gy (you should see some warnings in the output), or /OPT:REF, /OPT:ICF  (check project properties/linker/optimization),  or - very unlikely - you're unknowingly running some phase of PGO instrumentation.